# Why do different methods give different numbers of pixels in an image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to figure out why I get different answers when calculating the total number of pixels in an image in different ways.

1. Calculate a histogram on all possible values, then add together all of the categories to get the total number of pixels. This won't count NA's.
2. Use the `ee.Reducer.count()` function. This also doesn't count NA's, so I would expect this to give the same answer as number 1.
3. Use `unmask().ee.Reducer.count()` function. This DOES count NA's, so it will be larger than number 2 if there are NA's.
4. print the image, look at the dimensions, and multiply the 2 dimensions to get the number of pixels. This should count NA's and I would expect it to give the same answer as number 3.

Why do these methods give different counts of the total number of pixels in an image?

Sample code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2c4767f13001604254fa7d431af14b86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all the details to explain *all* of the differences you are seeing, but I can say that (1) is substantially different from (2) and (3) because the `reduceRegion` call for (1) has a `scale` specified and the other two do not. I don't recall exactly how the default scale is determined, to compare the (2) and (3) cases with (4). But [the documentation does say](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale) that it's a good idea to always explicitly specify a scale. Once you do, the exact pixel resolution of the image no longer affects what you're measuring, only the area it covers.

Also, (1) is not an integer apparently because of [weighting](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting) of partially masked pixels, in that adding `.unweighted()` to the histogram reducer gives an integer consistent with the `count()`. The partially masked pixels will come from the original image pixels not exactly fitting up to the edges of the pixels of the reduction.

Comment: Interestingly, adding the `.unweighted()` option to the reducer makes the estimate from the histogram even *further* from the other estimates! It decreases the number of pixels calculated from 4801.474509803917 with the weighting to 4800 without.

Comment: @filups21 You need to set the same scale before comparing different reductions, as I said in the first paragraph. They all give 4800 under the modifications I mentioned with a scale parameter of 1000, or 5620 with the default scale.